# Postgresql - Check constraint with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I am working check constraint into one table, I have status and status_sub_type columns, but for example my status 'Closed' only can be `status_subtype = 'Closed-typeA'` or `Closed-typeB'`, but right now I just put available `status_subtypes` into my check constraint, How I can put a condition to say that exists 5 subtypes but if it is status Closed, only can insert 2 different subtypes?

```
if status = 'close' 
   then status_subtype in ('closed-typeA', 'closed-typeB')
else if status = 'open' 
   then status_subtype in ('open-typeA', 'open-typeB')
else if status = 'Active' 
   then status_subtype = ''


| Status | Subtype      |
|---------------------- |
| Closed | Closed-TypeA |
| Closed | Closed-TypeB |
| Open   | Open-TypeA.  |
| Open   | Open-TypeB.  |
| Active |              |
```

Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Core.person 
(
    person_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    person_name varchar(200),
    status varchar(25) 
        CHECK (status IN ('Closed','Open','Active')),
    status_subtype varchar(25) 
        CHECK (status_subtype IN ('Closed-TypeA', 'Closed-TypeB', 'Open-TypeA', 'Open-TypeB'))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a normalized design you would deal with this requirement by creating 2 tables: one for all possible statuses and the other for the subtypes of the statuses and in the table `person` you would only have 1 foreign key referencing the subtype of the status.

For your design you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    person_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    person_name varchar(200),
    status varchar(25) CHECK (status IN ('Closed','Open','Active')),
    status_subtype varchar(25) 
    CHECK(CASE status
            WHEN 'Closed' THEN status_subtype IN ('Closed-TypeA','Closed-TypeB')
            WHEN 'Open' THEN status_subtype IN ('Open-TypeA','Open-TypeB')
            WHEN 'Active' THEN status_subtype = ''
          END  
         )
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=86cd554c31878de9190398c1d825ec30).

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    person_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    person_name varchar(200),
    status varchar(25) CHECK (status IN ('Closed','Open','Active')),
    status_subtype varchar(25) 
    CHECK(
          (status= 'Closed' AND status_subtype IN ('Closed-TypeA','Closed-TypeB'))
          OR
          (status= 'Open' AND status_subtype IN ('Open-TypeA','Open-TypeB'))
          OR
          (status= 'Active' AND status_subtype = '')
         )
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=660c894a5c7f5820c0f30475825a824d).